# c++ access main objects from other file

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, instantiation

I wonder how it is possible to access an object that was created in the main function from another class.

main.cpp

```
#include"ClassA.h";
#include"ClassB.h";

int main()
{

  ClassA objectA;

  return 0;
}
```

ClassA.h

```
#pragma once

class ClassA
{
  public:
  ClassA():_privateVar(100)
  {};
  ~ClassA()
  {};

  //Getters
  float getPrivateVarA(){ return _privateVarA; };

  //Setters
  void setPrivateVarA(float privateVarA){ _privateVarA = privateVarA; };

private:

  //Just a value
  float _privateVarA;

 };
```

ClassB.h

```
#pragma once

class ClassB
{
  public:
  ClassB():_privateVarB(50)
  { };
  ~ClassB()
  { };

  //This is what i´m trying to achieve: Acces objectA
  // like this:  objectA.getPrivateVarA(); or objectA.setPrivateVarA; 

  int getPrivateVarB(){return _privateVarB;};


private:
  int _privateVarB;
};
```

I've been all week searching for an answer to this and found nothing...
If anyone knows of some books or have any information on how I can get there would be grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the error you're getting and what have you tried?

Comment: From a C++ language point of view, what you are trying to do does not make sense. If you can describe the real problem you are trying to solve, there might be a way.

Comment: yes i did, i can´t access objectA from classB, i only can access ClassA.h but this is not going to afect my object since i´m accesing without objectA.get...

Comment: you should definitely add #ifndef #define and #endif statements. Hello anybody are you guys going to think about child and parent class inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed your question in the middle of the ClassB declaration. You can't execute code there. Whatever you do must be done from within a function.

A function in ClassB can be defined so that it accepts a reference or pointer to a ClassA. Then that reference can be used to call getPrivateVarA().

In other words, if class B needs to access a class A then it is up to your code to initialize B with the required reference.  This can be done when creating the B object, or when calling a method of the B object.

Comment: So if i´m get it right, i need too instantiate all my objects in main.cpp at main function and from there pass by reference to any method(class &objA), this is what it should be, and if my objectA have any dependencie from classB i will simply call that dependecie from my main.cpp for example: if(objectB.getValue() == true){ objectA.doSomething(); };

Comment: Or it will be something like: ClassB objB(ClassA &objA); , and in ClassB have a //Declaration Class A;   and a //constructor ClassB(ClassA &objA); ?

Comment: Yes passing a reference to the B constructor is a good way if B will need to save a reference to an A.

Answer (score 0):

`objectA` has function-local scope within main(). By definition, objects can be directly accessed only within their visible scope. That's what C++ is all about.

Of course, if you pass a reference or a pointer to this object, to some other function, that other function can access the instantiated object indirectly, via the pointer or the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say with 100% certainty that you can't, but you definitely should **not** be doing that. If you want to use an object created in a different scope then you need to pass it into the scope you want to access it from either by value, reference or via a pointer.

First Class A:

```
class A {
public:
    ClassA() : _privateVar(100) {}
    ~ClassA() {}
    float getPrivateVarA() { return _privateVar; }
    void setPrivateVarA(float val) { _privateVar = val; }
private:
    float _privateVar;
};
```

First Class B:

```
class B {
public:
    ClassB() : _privateVar(50) {}
    ~ClassB() {}
    // by copy
    float getPrivateVarB_byCopy(ClassA a) {
        return _privateVar + a.getPrivateVarA();
    }
    // by reference
    float getPrivateVarB_byRef(ClassA &a) {
        return _privateVar + a.getPrivateVarA();
    }
    // by pointer
    float getPrivateVarB_byPointer(ClassA *a) {
        return _privateVar + a->getPrivateVarA();
    }
    float setPrivateVarB(float val) { _privateVar = val; }
private:
    float _privateVar;
};
```

Now for main.

```
int main(void) {
    ClassB b;
    ClassA a; // for copy and ref
    ClassA *a2 = new ClassA(); // for pointer

    b.getPrivateVarB_byCopy(a); // => 150
    b.getPrivateVarB_byRef(a); // => 150
    b.getPrivateVarB_byPointer(a2); // => 150

    delete a2; // clean up pointer

    return 0;
}
```

Although your example this type of access is really not a good idea, not sure why you'd want to go about doing things this way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Ok I've noticed that I am not doing things the best way, I'm learning C ++ a few days, and the idea that I have to access the objects is to define them as global, but I know it is not a good practice, so I'm trying to access the objects in it but not being defined as global, and this is where my problem is, I do not know how to access objects that are not global, there is a simpler way to do this? I've read somewhere that using vectors that is a good way but did not know much about vectors

Comment: I just showed you how you would access a `ClassA` from `ClassB` without any of them being global. You're going to have learn a lot more than just C++ in order to fully grasp your goal. Especially if you're only seeing things in the form of globals which should be the farthest from your mind as you develop.